# COUNT(*) not working in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, sql, exchangewebservices

Hi Believe the problem is with the C# code itself and not the SQL statement, as I have outputted the SQL to the screen and run it direct into the database.

For example

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) 
 FROM meeting_room.meeting_acceptance 
 WHERE meeting_id = 'AAMkADY3MDk3NTdiLTE4M2ItNDk4ZS1hNmZjLWJmMDhkYTBiMDVjYgBGAAAAAAB+oqKzNnIvRZgdzn8wIE0XBwC62mlG2pRhSKvV6Bc2NH7rAAAALqU/AAC62mlG2pRhSKvV6Bc2NH7rAAAp5DTDAAA=';
```

Returns 1, although when outputting the "NoRows" variable, 0 still appears, any ideas?

```
if ((Appoint.End > DateTime.Now) && (Appoint.Start < DateTime.Now))
{
   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection mycon3 = new MySqlConnection(GetConnectionString());

   if (mycon3.State != ConnectionState.Open)
       try
       {
           mycon3.Open();


       }
       catch (MySqlException ex)
       {
           throw (ex);
       }

   using (mycon3)
   sql = "SELECT count(*) from meeting_room.meeting_acceptance where meeting_id = '" + Appoint.Id + "';";

   Label1.Text = sql;
    using (MySqlCommand mcmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, mycon3))
        try
        {
                using (MySqlDataReader datareader = mcmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (datareader.Read())
                    {
                        NoRows = Convert.ToInt32(datareader.GetValue(0));
                    }
                }
        }
       catch
       {
           Error.Text = "SQL Exception 2" ;
           sqlerror = true;
       }

    Success.Text = NoRows.ToString();
    if ( NoRows == 0 )
    {
        ConfirmLink.Text = "<div align=\"center\"><a href=\"?RoomID=" + RoomID + "&Confirm=" + Appoint.Id.ToString().Replace(" ","") + "\"><img src=\"Confirm.jpg\" alt=\"confirm\" /></a></div>";
        if (DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-2) > Appoint.Start)


{
        Error.Text = "Would have deleted meeting";
    //  Appoint.CancelMeeting("The meeting you created for the " + resource_name + " on " + Appoint.Start + " Subject: " + Appoint.Subject + " has been deleted as you did not accept the meeting");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Consider using parameterized queries - this line is open to SQL injection: `sql = "SELECT count(*) from meeting_room.meeting_acceptance where meeting_id = '" + Appoint.Id + "';"`

Comment: I would have done, but Appoint.Id isn't derived from a user, its from the Microsoft EWS class

Answer (score 2):

You need to use ExecuteScalar method

```
int count = (int) (mcmd.ExecuteScalar() ?? 0);
```

Also you have not enclosed the using block properly..Your code should look like

```
using(MySqlConnection mycon3 = new ....)
{
    try
    {
        mycon3.Open();
        //your commands
    }
    catch(SqlException e){}
}
```

Also your query is vulnerable to sql injection attack..Consider using [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: it will make exception if you get null from cmd.ExecuteScalar().

Comment: Hmm still get 0 - I've changed
       NoRows = (int)(mcmd.ExecuteScalar() ?? 0);

Comment: @CorbinSpicer you haven't opened the connection..`mcmd.Open()`

Comment: I open the connection here: 

      if (mycon3.State != ConnectionState.Open)
                                       try
                                       {
                                           mycon3.Open();


                                       }
                                       catch (MySqlException ex)
                                       {
                                           throw (ex);
                                       }

Comment: @CorbinSpicer remove `using(mycon3)`..it's closing the connection

Comment: @CorbinSpicer update your question with your current code..Also consider the pattern in my ans..

Comment: @CorbinSpicer you don't need `using (MySqlDataReader datareader = mcmd.ExecuteReader())` block..Remove that **complete** block and use `NoRows = (int)(mcmd.ExecuteScalar() ?? 0);` instead

Comment: I've converted a lot over to your suggested block and now nothing is working haha - will keep debugging

Comment: @Anirudh - I'm now really stuck, all I get is mysql exceptions - I've changed my code to follow what you said - full code:

http://pastebin.com/Q4r2ZE79

Comment: I have it working in my format now - I know it probably needs optimizing to your way and if you can help explain that a bit more I would be very grateful

Answer (score 0):

```
Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

if you try to do explict conversion then it make a exception. `Convert.ToInt32` will gave you 0 if result is null.

Your code doesn't use SQL-Parameter so it will be unsafe. use Sql parameter to make your code safer from Sql-injection.